# Use {noformat} code block {noformat} in Confluence

Tags: markup, confluence

So I am migrating my Wordpress site over to Confluence because I started using Jira to actually keep track of things vs notepad logs then posting on Wordpress. I'd like to be able to copy things directly from my Jira posts over to Confluence once they are finalized/sanitized for public viewing.

All my Jira posts use the following :

```
{noformat}
this is a code block
{noformat}
```

But if I copy that into Confluence, it justs shows the {noformat} block on the page vs rending in a code block.

I read this, but can't seem to understand/make it work. I found the option to create a user macro, but its not easy to understand, and perhaps not what I want. But the page title seems to be explicitly what I want! Frustrating that they wouldn't make things work cross site platforms when they develop both Products!

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/noformat-macro-139545.html

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/14/CSP-186163 , first time opening a ticket with Atlassian, lets see if they respond :)

Comment: Error 404 :( Guess Atlassian doesn't care. Also love how Confluence Local Sever instance is no longer being supported. My love for Atlassion < my love for Open Source.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the + Symbol >> "Markup" >> Copy Code >> Insert

If you copy code directly into the Editor, it doesn't render the {noformat} macro, what you need to use is the Wiki Markup tool. You can insert the code, and it will render it correctly. Its another step for me, but it works!

If you just type {noformart} it will create a macro window to paste code into, this will work great for future new posts, but not for me migrating posts from JIRA.

[image]